# how To change my regex to reject underscores

Tags: java, regex, validation

Currently have this regex string in my java code:

```
^[\\w\\-\\ \\#\\.\\/]{0,70}$
```

It successfully accepts those characters, however it also accepts underscore, how can modify the regex to reject underscore appearing anywhere in the string?

Comment: `^[-#. a-zA-Z0-9\\/]{0,70}$` should work.

Comment: It is because of`\w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is:

```
^[\\w\\-\\ \\#\\.\\/]{0,70}$
```

It is using `\w` which is equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, hence it allows underscore also.

You can change your character class to this:

```
^[-#. a-zA-Z0-9\\/]{0,70}$
```

Note that space, dot, `#`, `/` don't need to be escaped inside `[...]` and `-` if placed at first or last position doesn't require escaping either.

Comment: RegEx Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ByMyBl/1